# Saving attribute forms' widget types and their premade values to shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, fields-attributes, save

I am trying to create 'template' shapefiles. I edited the attribute forms and changed the widget types (ex. value map) with custom values. When I try to export the shapefile this way

[image]

[image]

I end up with default widgets when I try to use the shapefiles in a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You additionally have to save the layer style to a `.qml` file. Widgets and forms are saved there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do I have to manually load style for each individual layer each time I try to set up a project?

Comment: If you save the `.qml` using the same name as the shape to the same location, it will be loaded when you load the shapefile to your QGIS. Easiest way to achieve this is to hit the little `style` button at the bottom of the layer properties window and choose `save as default`.

Comment: I see. As of right now, the way we set up project is through importing the template shapefiles into a brand new QGZ project then manually export each shapefile into the proper project's folder with a different name (from "Linelayer Template" to "Linelayer ABC1" for example) then deleting the previously imported layers from the project in that intance would the default style file still apply ?

Comment: Nope, then you'd need to load it again. Why don't you use the Explorer to copy the shapes to the project folder, rename and then load them?

Comment: Ohh, so the style file is only tied to the shapefile as opposed to a project! I'd only have to batch rename all the files including the style files then just load them into the project for everything to work. That'd make things faster. edit: Thank you for your insight!